# automatically copy static files like css or js from a Blazor component lib into the app's wwwroot

Tags: blazor, shared-libraries, blazor-webassembly, visual-studio-2022, output-directory

I searched a lot, read about MsBuild, post-build jobs, csproj-config, but did not succeed with this:

**Static files (like css or js) sitting in a Blazor component lib are not copied to the final app's wwwroot folder**

What I have:

- A Blazor webassembly (.Net6, client-side) project as consumer.
- a Razor-Lib-project as library for reusable controls such as notifications
- some more, but irrelevant here

The lib has its own `wwwroot` with css and scripts.

During build the files are finally found in `TheConsumerProject\bin\Debug\net6.0\wwwroot`. But when debugging with IIS Express (directly from VS) the files should be loaded from `TheConsumerProject\wwwroot`. That fails... When I copied the files manually it worked.

The goal: Any consumer should not need to configure anything special. Just reference the lib and get all in place.

I found

- `<StaticWebAssetBasePath>` to be specified in the lib's csproj but did not manage to get any further with this.
- hints to `<Target>` with copy jobs using `$(MsBuildVariable)`. This actually worked, the files were copied to a specified destination, but I did not find a variable pointing to the final app's `wwwroot`.
- Some tweaks with `<ItemGroup>` but nothing worked.

I do NOT want to use any project specific data, like relative paths. This should work with any project structure if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The files from the Razor Class Library project should not be copied into the project referencing it (i.e. your Blazor frontend).  The runtime does some magical rerouting.

In the page where you want to consume those static assets, you should use a URL such as `_content/YourClassLibraryName/path-from-wwwroot`.  For example, if you have a file like flair.css in your wwwroot folder in the RCL, you would import it in the frontend project as

```
<link href="_content/YourClassLibraryName/flair.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Similarly, an image file such as solarFlare.png sitting in your wwwroot/img folder would be:

`YourClassLibraryName` could either be a project name or a NuGet package name, if you're consuming the RCL via NuGet.  They should behave the same.

Docs:

- [Consume ASP.NET Core Razor components from Razor class libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#create-an-rcl-with-static-assets-in-the-wwwroot-folder)
- [Create reusable UI using the Razor class library project in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#create-an-rcl-with-static-assets-1)